# How to get FreeForm to allow zip files?

Tags: solspace-freeform

I am pretty sure I am just doing something wrong, because this seems to be a straight forward thing I am trying to do, but not having any luck at the moment.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am trying to get a FreeForm form to allow zip files in a file upload field, but I am getting the following error: "The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed."

What I have done so far:
- Checked the file upload field's settings and made sure the "Allowed File Types" setting includes "zip". ie. I have it set as "zip|pdf|doc|docx|odt". (Note: uploads work fine with pdf's, doc's, etc.)
- Tried adding the "allowed_file_types" parameter to the {exp:freeform:form} tag, but I think this is deprecated. I am using FreeForm v4.1.3
- Made sure that there is a mime type entry for "zip" in /system/expressionengine/config/mimes.php
- Made sure I have full permissions on the upload directory.

Is there anything else I can try? Like I said, I can upload other files without any problems, so it seems to only be specific to zip files.

Comment: Have you tried disabling *Apply XSS Filtering to uploaded files?* in **Admin -> Security and Sessions**?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @DerekHogue I tried that again now and still no luck.

Comment: maybe you have to add zip to the EE mime types php file

Comment: @JelleDijkstra The mime type for zip files already existed in the default EE config/mimes.php file, but I managed to update it to also include 'application/octet-stream' which for some reason was the mime type of the zip files I tried uploading. Not sure if this is the greatest solution, but these zip files are legitimate zip files.